# How to calcute future datetime after few workinghours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate what date will be after 2 or more working hours from now even if I'll start calculating on weekend or after workhours it should be like:
working hours are from 8am to 4pm
I start calculating at Friday at 3pm so if I'll start calculating result should be Monday 9am

```
      if(@data_przyj>@WorkStart AND DATEPART(DATEADD(MINUTE,@ileNaZapytanie,@data_przyj)<@WorkFinish)
       BEGIN
            while  (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7))
             BEGIN
                 SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate)
                 SET @czyBylPrzeskok =1
             END
             if (@czyBylPrzeskok =1)
                BEGIN
                    SET @LastDay = @CurrentDate
                    SET @LastDay = DATEADD(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @data_przyj)),@WorkStart), @LastDay)
                    SET @LastDay = DATEADD(HOUR, datediff(MINUTE,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, @data_przyj)),@WorkStart), @LastDay)
                END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @LastDay =  DATEADD(MINUTE,@ileNaZapytanie,@data_przyj)
            END
            SET @IsCalculated = 1
       END
      else if(@data_przyj>@WorkStart AND DATEADD(MINUTE,@ileNaZapytanie,@data_przyj)>@WorkFinish)
       BEGIN
            SET @LastDay =DateADD(DD,3,GETDATE());
            SET @IsCalculated = 1
       END
       else if(@data_przyj<@WorkStart )
       BEGIN
            SET @LastDay =GETDATE();
            SET @IsCalculated = 1
       END
    END
```

EDIT: 
for example working hours:8:00 - 16:00 i have Date '2019-09-06 15:00' so after adding 2 working hours should be '2019-09-09 09:00', for date '2019-09-06 13:00'  should be '2019-09-06 15:00'  etc

Comment: What about public holidays?

Comment: i have in base all holidays so i just can check same as  if date is weekend but hardest part is calculate it

Comment: That didn't really answer my question.

Comment: at this moment holidays can be skipped

Comment: @garondi5 . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for example working hours:8:00 - 16:00 i have Date '2019-09-06 15:00' so after adding 2 working hours should be '2019-09-09 09:00', for date '2019-09-06 13:00' should be '2019-09-06 15:00' etc

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses a calendar table with working hours, then use a rolling sum to accumulate each day's business hours and find which day you need to end with.

Using a calendar table will give you the flexibility of having different business time periods and very easily adding or removing holidays.

**Setup** (calendar table):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#WorkingCalendar') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #WorkingCalendar

CREATE TABLE #WorkingCalendar (
    Date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    IsWorkingDay BIT,
    WorkingStartTime DATETIME,
    WorkingEndTime DATETIME)

SET DATEFIRST 1 -- 1: Monday, 7: Sunday

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2030-01-01'

;WITH RecursiveDates AS
(
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = @StartDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, R.GeneratedDate)
    FROM
        RecursiveDates AS R
    WHERE
        R.GeneratedDate < @EndDate
)
INSERT INTO #WorkingCalendar (
    Date,
    IsWorkingDay,
    WorkingStartTime,
    WorkingEndTime)
SELECT
    Date = R.GeneratedDate,
    IsWorkingDay = CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, R.GeneratedDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 -- From Monday to Friday
        ELSE 0 END,
    WorkingStartTime = CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, R.GeneratedDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 
        THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, R.GeneratedDate) + CONVERT(DATETIME, '08:00:00') END,
    WorkingEndTime = CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, R.GeneratedDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 
        THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, R.GeneratedDate) + CONVERT(DATETIME, '16:00:00') END
FROM
    RecursiveDates AS R
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Generates a table like the following:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|    Date    | IsWorkingDay |    WorkingStartTime     |     WorkingEndTime      |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2019-01-01 |            1 | 2019-01-01 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-01 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-02 |            1 | 2019-01-02 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-02 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-03 |            1 | 2019-01-03 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-03 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-04 |            1 | 2019-01-04 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-04 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-05 |            0 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| 2019-01-06 |            0 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| 2019-01-07 |            1 | 2019-01-07 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-07 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-08 |            1 | 2019-01-08 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-08 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-09 |            1 | 2019-01-09 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-09 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-10 |            1 | 2019-01-10 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-10 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-11 |            1 | 2019-01-11 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-11 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-12 |            0 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| 2019-01-13 |            0 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| 2019-01-14 |            1 | 2019-01-14 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-14 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-15 |            1 | 2019-01-15 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-15 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-16 |            1 | 2019-01-16 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-16 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-01-17 |            1 | 2019-01-17 08:00:00.000 | 2019-01-17 16:00:00.000 |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**Proposed Solution**:

```
DECLARE @v_BusinessHoursToAdd INT = 2

DECLARE @v_CurrentDateTimeHour DATETIME = '2019-09-06 15:00'


;WITH CalendarFromNow AS
(
    SELECT
        T.Date,
        WorkingStartTime = CASE 
            WHEN @v_CurrentDateTimeHour BETWEEN T.WorkingStartTime AND T.WorkingEndTime THEN @v_CurrentDateTimeHour 
            ELSE T.WorkingStartTime END,
        WorkingEndTime = T.WorkingEndTime
    FROM
        #WorkingCalendar AS T
    WHERE
        T.Date >= CONVERT(DATE, @v_CurrentDateTimeHour) AND
        T.IsWorkingDay = 1
),
RollingBusinessSum AS
(
    SELECT
        C.Date,
        C.WorkingStartTime,
        C.WorkingEndTime,
        AmountBusinessHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR, C.WorkingStartTime, C.WorkingEndTime),
        RollingBusinessHoursSum = SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, C.WorkingStartTime, C.WorkingEndTime)) OVER (ORDER BY C.Date),
        PendingHours = @v_BusinessHoursToAdd - SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, C.WorkingStartTime, C.WorkingEndTime)) OVER (ORDER BY C.Date)
    FROM
        CalendarFromNow AS C
)
SELECT TOP 1
    EndingHour = DATEADD(
        HOUR, 
        R.PendingHours,
        R.WorkingEndTime)
FROM
    RollingBusinessSum AS R
WHERE
    R.PendingHours < 0
ORDER BY
    R.Date
```

**Explanation**:

The first CTE **CalendarFromNow** is simply filtering the calendar dates from the current hour's date and reducing the starting working datetime to the current hour, since this is gonna be the starting point to count hours from.

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|    Date    |    WorkingStartTime     |     WorkingEndTime      |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-06 15:00:00.000 | 2019-09-06 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-09-09 | 2019-09-09 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-09 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-09-10 | 2019-09-10 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-10 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-09-11 | 2019-09-11 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-11 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-09-12 | 2019-09-12 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-12 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-09-13 | 2019-09-13 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-13 16:00:00.000 |
| 2019-09-16 | 2019-09-16 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-16 16:00:00.000 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

The second CTE **RollingBusinessSum** is calculating the amount of business hours on each day and accumulating them over the days. The last column **PendingHours** is the result of the amount of hours we need to add from now subtracted by the sum of business hours over the days.

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
|    Date    |    WorkingStartTime     |     WorkingEndTime      | AmountBusinessHours | RollingBusinessHoursSum | PendingHours |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| 2019-09-06 | 2019-09-06 15:00:00.000 | 2019-09-06 16:00:00.000 |                   1 |                       1 |            1 |
| 2019-09-09 | 2019-09-09 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-09 16:00:00.000 |                   8 |                       9 |           -7 |
| 2019-09-10 | 2019-09-10 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-10 16:00:00.000 |                   8 |                      17 |          -15 |
| 2019-09-11 | 2019-09-11 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-11 16:00:00.000 |                   8 |                      25 |          -23 |
| 2019-09-12 | 2019-09-12 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-12 16:00:00.000 |                   8 |                      33 |          -31 |
| 2019-09-13 | 2019-09-13 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-13 16:00:00.000 |                   8 |                      41 |          -39 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Finally the first day that the **PendingHours** column is negative is the day that we arrived at the amount of hours we wanted to add. This is the `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY`. To get the final datetime, we just subtract the pending hours to the end time for that particular day.

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+
|    Date    |    WorkingStartTime     |     WorkingEndTime      | AmountBusinessHours | RollingBusinessHoursSum | PendingHours |       EndingHour        |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+
| 2019-09-09 | 2019-09-09 08:00:00.000 | 2019-09-09 16:00:00.000 |                   8 |                       9 |           -7 | 2019-09-09 09:00:00.000 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

You might have to tweak performance and do boundary tests but this might give you a flexible idea of how to work with working hours at holidays or different time periods.